# Azure DevOps - Portfolio Plans (beta) - settings and access

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, portfolio, azure-boards

I have created a plan with the help of Portfolio Plans (beta) under Boards, but I do not understand who have access or permission to see my plan. Does anybody know how I can let everybody in the project see my Portfolio Plan?

Also, I would like to change the description for my plan. Where do I edit that?

Thank you!
/Mimmi

Answer (score 0):

1. All the users in the organization with **Analytics permissions** can see the plan. You can refer to the **Requirements** in the bottom of [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension&ssr=false#overview).

   To let everybody in the project see your Portfolio Plan, you need to set permissions to access Analytics and Analytics views for them. You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-security?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps.
2. You can’t change the description for your plan because *once inside Portfolio Plans you can only change one setting, which is how you want progress tracking to be calculated – in either effort or count of completed style*. You can also refer to [this article](https://ppmblog.org/2019/07/21/devops-new-portfolio-plan-extension/).

   For this feature, I suggest that you make a new feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/featuretimeline/issues?utm_source=vsmp&utm_medium=ms%20web&utm_campaign=mpdetails).